# Validate if numbers are valid within a given range, depending on used pre-selection

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing a program that generates n number of bonuses, it does well but when it comes to generate their id numbers i am stuck. The program at that point needs the user to tell the program a `Min` value and a `Max` value between `10000` and `10000`, until there no problem all easy.

The part after it is making me scratch my head because the program needs to know how many numbers can be generated at a given position of the value generated so it's not a fixed range, the ids generated must and only include the numbers that the user specified for every x position and it has to know that so when it's reading the values that are going to be used for that purpose, they get verified for it's corresponding position.

I have tried to use some some conditions for some cases that i have identified within the working program, but i'm actually stuck because it seems like ill have to build a lot of if statements to contain all of the possible types of ids that can occur.

```java
       // from left to right the "positions"
       int min = 1 0 0 0 0;
       int max = 1 0 9 9 9;

       int temp = max - min;
        // tells how many different digits can be used from 1 to 10 for each position (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        // leftmost position aka first
        delta[0] = temp / 10000;
        // aka second position
        delta[1] = (temp % 10000) / 1000;
        // aka third position
        delta[2] = ((temp % 10000) % 1000) / 100;
        // aka fourth position
        delta[3] = (((temp % 10000) % 1000) % 100) / 10;
        // aka fifth position
        delta[4] = ((((temp % 10000) % 1000) % 100) % 10);
```

these formulas work as expected, however when a given position resets there is no way for the formulas to say "you can include all 10 digits on this position because it's not just 0, it's 10000 to 10999".

**[EDIT]**

To clarify the question above, i am required by my teacher to do the following in order to generate the bonuses id numbers:

- ask the user a range (inclusive) between 10000 and 99999. this means that i can only generate 5 digit ids for a given amount of bonuses, they should not repeat.
- also ask the user numbers allowed for every position within that 5 digits range given, i.e. my range goes from `12000 to 22000`, from left to right of the 5 digits that can be generated user says that he only wants the number 1 to appear so that now limits my ids to generate to values from `12000 to 19999`... but he can also say that he only wants the number 2 to be at that particular position so the opposite might happen as well (from `20000 to 22000` ids are only possible to be used). this applies for all 5 digits that can be generated at any given range between min and max.

Comment: I read your question 3 times and I have no clue what exactly you intend to do respectively where you are stuck. What do you mean by resetting a position? Please step back and try to tell us exactly what input you have, and what the results of your code are supposed to be!

Comment: I just added more information about where i am stuck so it's easier to understand what i need to accomplish. When a position resets is when you get a 0 instead of a 9, having a bigger number before, lets say a 2 so it would look like 20.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much, much simpler to keep a List of numbers, generate your ids randomly, and compare, like so:

```java
public class IdGenerator {

  private static List<Integer> usedIds = new ArrayList<>();

  ... (other fields and methods here)

  public int generateNumber() {
    // Check if all ids are used. (Redesign your ID scheme to prevent this situation, otherwise you'll run out of IDs and your application will stop working.
    if (usedIds.size() >= 1000) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("All allowable IDs used, please free up an ID to continue generation.");
    }

    // Generate a random ID with a value between 10000 and 10999.
    int idCandidate = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000, 10999 + 1);

    // ID in use, try again with new number.
    if (usedIds.contains(idCandidate) {
      return generateNumber();
    }

    // ID is not taken and can therefore be saved.
    usedIds.add(idCandidate);
    return idCandidate;
  }
}
```

Even better would to be to use [UUIDs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), since they are more or less guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: That would be the ideal solution i think... but i am required to do it differently.